# Probability Question, sanity check

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I am currently trying to determine a relationship between two values. Let's say there is a random variable $X(y)$ that defines a cube, and an empirical analogue of said random variable $X_n(y)$ which defines a cube defined by samples $X_n \sim P$. Let's assume that:
\begin{equation}
   |X_n - X| \leq \epsilon
\end{equation}
Now let's say we take a single sample from probability distribution $Q$ called y. Determining the probability that such a sample lies within these cubes, we focus on the quantity:
\begin{equation}
   \mathbb{P}_{y \sim Q}[X_n(y) > \Omega]  
\end{equation}
for some constant $\Omega$. Can I then use the inequality

\begin{equation}
   X(y) + \epsilon > X_n(y)
\end{equation}

to obtain the result:
\begin{equation}
   \mathbb{P}_{y \sim Q}[X_n(y) > \Omega] =
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 = \mathbb{P}_{y \sim Q}[ X(y) + \epsilon > X_n(y) > \Omega]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   = \mathbb{P}_{y \sim Q}[ X(y) + \epsilon > \Omega]
\end{equation}

My question is; do the last three lines follow given everything else I have provided?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your problem is, there are effectively two random variables representing squares $X$ and $X_n$. Suppose each random variable is the 'mass' of a square. $X + \epsilon$ is always a greater mass value than $X_n$. In essence then you are asking is $\mathbb{P}[X_n > \Omega] = \mathbb{P}[X+\epsilon > \Omega]$ ? If the 'mass' of $X_n$ has some probability of being larger than $\Omega$, then a 'mass' which is strictly larger than $X_n$ must have at least the same or greater probability. Thus
$$
\mathbb{P}[X_n >\Omega] \leq \mathbb{P}[X + \epsilon > \Omega]
$$

The root issue seems to me that you are substituting within the probability operator which one cannot do, as you are fundamentally asking a different question. It doesn't seem to me that $y\sim Q$ has much bearing on the problem itself.

Comment: unfortunately, due to privacy considerations I cannot be too explicit with my assumptions. that being said we assume that X and X_n are both dependent on y ~Q. We also assume that the assumption $| X - X_n | < \epsilon$ is a fixed relation. That being said, my key question is if the last three lines are incorrect, mathematically why are they not?